# Why Did Hal Jordan Use Jet Fighters?

Tags: dc, green-lantern, green-lantern-2011

Kind of tricky to make the question title clear without using spoilers, since the question gives a lot away.

At the end of the recent *Green Lantern* film:

> When Hal Jordan is battling Parallex and trying to make him fall into the Sun, he creates two jet fighters to pull him (Jordan) away from the Sun.  But jets need air to work, so they can't work in space.  Any pilot would know this (it's part of why jets have a ceiling).  Why did Jordan create fighter jets instead of, say, Saturn V rockets?  And how would the fighters have been able to pull him away from the Sun without air for the jet engines?

Comment: Maybe those were actually Saturn Vs disguised as jet fighters!

Comment: Kind of a stealth Saturn V so nobody would know what they are?

Comment: Technically, don';t the Saturn Vs need air too (just that they carry it in the mixture). since he makes the jet engines and the fuel from scratch, i would assume he can make the air from scratch. Since he is a pilot, he might know how to create a jet fighter better then a Saturn V rocket. Assuming he needs to know what he makes and not have a general idea of what it looks like.

Comment: Maybe they were giant momentum generators that happened to look like jet fighters - given that I doubt he knows how to actually create a jet fighter, the ring is really just looking for intent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look carefully, those jets (which, as ring constructs, work just fine in space) seem to be the AI jets he defeated in Act 1 of the movie*.  They were therefore FAR more powerful than Saturn V rockets would have been - they had important symbolism to Jordan.  They represented what he was trying to achieve: defeating an 'unbeatable' foe by doing the unexpected, by pushing beyond established limits and succeeding through sheer willpower.

The fighters he created could pull him away from the sun in the same way that the rope he created earlier in the movie kept him from falling into Killowag's star construct - he willed it to.

The ring's constructs are instruments of the wielder's willpower - they give shape to his thoughts.  People (generalized to all sentient species, here) tend to focus better with a clear mental image.  Try it: focus on implacability.  Hard, isn't it?  Instead, picture Juggernaut, marching stolidly ahead, not slowing for walls.  That was much easier, right?  Energy constructs have a familiar form because sentient minds focus best that way.  And focus determines the strength of your constructs.

*They may also be his and Carol's fighters from the same scene, I can't recall exactly, but it doesn't change my answer significantly if they are.  It may even be more significant to Hal if they were.